# Will it be possible to switch from systemd to upstart from 15.10 onwards?

Tags: boot, upstart, systemd

In Ubuntu 15.04, it is possible to switch from systemd to upstart.  Will this ability be retained going forward?

Comment: Your question needs a bit more clarity. I don't think the init binary provided by upstart is going away, but the devs aren't going to bother testing if anything works, or even if there are upstart configuration files for the various services. That's to say: you maybe able to specify it as the init binary, but after that... In quite a few cases, the upstart configuration was added by Ubuntu devs. They'll probably just stop adding the extra files.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely anyone will be able to answer this based on facts but I would assume that ...

- switching from GRUB like you can do now (at run time) is likely to disappear and this is also likely to happen when 16.04 LTS arrives. During the Ubuntu Developer Summit (UDS 14.03) Mark Shuttleworth announced that systemd will be used as default on the next LTS version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 16.04.
- but as long as the package is available you can install it yourself. [15.10 still has upstart](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/upstart). How well new services will be supported by upstart is anyone's guess. Even I myself doubt it will be supported.

So I assume the answer is yes but with increasingly difficulty. I would forget about upstart and get to know systemd. In this case I would advice to not swim against the current.

Comment: Switching from grub is unlikely to go away anytime soon, since the `init=foo` parameter is supported by the Linux kernel independent of Ubuntu and is a known, stable option.

Comment: True true. But you do need 100% compatibility between upstart and systemd. And that is unlikely. It would be a waste of resources to keep upstart maintained.