# Server 15.10 - "service whatever start" will not start 'whatever' system V init script in /etc/init.d/

Tags: server, services

it just says... "Failed to start whatever.service: Unit whatever.service failed to load: No such file or directory."

Looking at the man page for service it specifically says it's for starting system V init scripts in /etc/init.d/

I would use systemctl whatever start if I wanted to start a systemd unit.

I'm assuming system has been changed to make it 'compatible' but how do I get the old style startup script to work? I['ve added LSB into to it.

Comment: First off, your syntax is wrong - use `systemctl start whatever` . Second, very much unclear what you're asking. `whatever` isn't a good way to provide info. Tell us which service isn't working. If you want to go back go upstart, you can because it's [still included](http://askubuntu.com/a/670136/295286) in 15.10

Comment: And you could use the `war` file and deploy this on your Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some options

1. Install Tomcat - use the WAR file and deploy it to the Tomcat installation. Tomcat supports systemd and you can start/stop/restart Archiva in the Tomcat Admin console in a browser.
2. Use the Archiva standalone installation and start with `bin/archiva start`.
   The standalone installation does not support systemd out of the box.
3. Read the little story about `whatever` below

---

### The story of `deluged`

I never heard of a service called `whatever`, but ... okay ... **;)**

I know a service called `deluged` and here is its history:

There was a service called `deluged`. It was an old service and it had only a script for the old `init.d` system. Many years this was a big friendship. But `init.d` got too old and so Linux decided : "We need another system". And ... it happened - `systemd` was born.

However since many of the old services could not be used with the new system, the service had compassion. It provided the services with some kind of help, redirecting it to systemd-sysv, just like the `deluged` service:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable deluged
deluged.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable deluged
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `deluged' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `deluged' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

And what about the `whatever` service?

It waits … and waits … and waits …, perhaps it should ask `deluged` or any other `whatever` service …

Comment: ok, well... the actual service is apache archiva.

Comment: systemctl enable archiva worked (because I manually added the required LSB fields as comments)

Comment: but... "systemctl --now enable archiva" did not actually start it. Also, service archiva start still fails saying "Failed to start archiva.service: Unit archiva.service failed to load: No such file or directory." but the enable command did add correct symlinks to the RC#.d dirs

Comment: "systemctl start archiva" also fails with the same error service gives

Comment: I'll probably jsut go ahead and make a systemd service unit for this, but find it hard to believe the devs who made it couldn't be bothered to. Still - I feel like system-V compatibility is not working correctly in 15.10

Comment: Please update your question.